# no Task is currently running

Tags: rust

I am getting an error: `no Task is currently running` when I attempt to use `UnboundedSender` and `UnboundedReceiver` without using `tokio::run()`.

This is the error:

```
Press Ctrl-C to abort
thread 'receiver thread' panicked at 'no Task is currently running', src/libcore/option.rs:1166:5
stack backtrace:
   0: backtrace::backtrace::libunwind::trace
             at /cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/backtrace-0.3.29/src/backtrace/libunwind.rs:88
   1: backtrace::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized
             at /cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/backtrace-0.3.29/src/backtrace/mod.rs:66
   2: std::sys_common::backtrace::_print
             at src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:47
   3: std::sys_common::backtrace::print
             at src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:36
   4: std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:200
   5: std::panicking::default_hook
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:214
   6: std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:477
   7: std::panicking::continue_panic_fmt
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:384
   8: rust_begin_unwind
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:311
   9: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at src/libcore/panicking.rs:85
  10: core::option::expect_failed
             at src/libcore/option.rs:1166
  11: core::option::Option<T>::expect
             at /rustc/dddb7fca09dc817ba275602b950bb81a9032fb6d/src/libcore/option.rs:345
  12: futures::task_impl::with
             at /home/nickhash/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/futures-0.1.29/src/task_impl/mod.rs:46
  13: futures::task_impl::current
             at /home/nickhash/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/futures-0.1.29/src/task_impl/mod.rs:118
  14: futures::sync::mpsc::Receiver<T>::try_park
             at /home/nickhash/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/futures-0.1.29/src/sync/mpsc/mod.rs:902
  15: <futures::sync::mpsc::Receiver<T> as futures::stream::Stream>::poll
             at /home/nickhash/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/futures-0.1.29/src/sync/mpsc/mod.rs:936
  16: <futures::sync::mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<T> as futures::stream::Stream>::poll
             at /home/nickhash/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/futures-0.1.29/src/sync/mpsc/mod.rs:1004
  17: fut2::launch_receiver_thread::{{closure}}
             at src/main.rs:16
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
^C
```

The code I am running is:

```
use std:: {thread,time::Duration};
use futures::stream::*;
use futures::prelude::*;


fn launch_sender_thread(tx: futures::sync::mpsc::UnboundedSender<()>) {
    let _ = thread::Builder::new().name("sender thread".to_string()).spawn(move || {
        loop {
            tx.clone().send(());
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(3000));
        }   
    });
}
fn launch_receiver_thread(mut rx: futures::sync::mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<()>) {
    let _ = thread::Builder::new().name("receiver thread".to_string()).spawn(move || {
        match rx.poll() {
            Ok(Async::Ready(Some(_))) => {
                println!("thread2: received data");
            },  
            Ok(_) => (), 
            Err(err) => {
                println!("poll err {:?}",err);
            },
        } 
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
    });
}

fn main() {

    let (sender, receiver) = futures::sync::mpsc::unbounded::<()>();
    launch_receiver_thread(receiver);
    launch_sender_thread(sender);
    println!("Press Ctrl-C to abort");
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10000000));        
}
```

So, basically I want to send and receive data from one thread to another , but without using the `Future` object, is this possible?
If it is not possible, then how do I fix this error with a minimal use of Futures crate ? The requirement is to use `futures::sync::mpsc::UnboundedSender` and `futures::sync::mpsc::UnboundedSender` for communication.

**Cargo.toml:**

```
[package]
name = "fut2"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
futures = { version = "0.1" }
```

Comment: when I place the content of the functions in the `main()` this error disappears, so probably it is some threading issue.

Comment: If you don't want to use futures, why do you use `futures::sync::mpsc` instead of [`std::sync::mpsc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/mpsc/index.html)?

Comment: @Jmb it was the requirement of the User to use `futures::sync::mpsc`, since the project I am working with is more complex than this minimal example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but without using the Future object, is this possible?

It is possible to use `UnboundedSender` and `UnboundedSender` with minimum interaction with futures crate, but you have to use futures with tasks. This is not entirely your fault though; the futures documentation and API design aren't very clear about this. In its `0.2` incarnation, there will be a [task context](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/futures-rfcs/blob/master/task-context.md) explicitly threaded through various API calls. For example, [`Stream::poll`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.29/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#tymethod.poll) in `0.1.x` is defined as:

```rust
fn poll(&mut self) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>, Self::Error>
```

In `0.2.x`, it is [`Stream::poll_next`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.2.1/futures/trait.Stream.html#tymethod.poll_next):

```rust
fn poll_next(
    &mut self, 
    cx: &mut Context
) -> Result<Async<Option<Self::Item>>, Self::Error>
```

So you won't be able to make the same mistake of polling outside of a task.

Until then this works with `0.1.x` futures crate:

```rust
use futures::sync::mpsc::{UnboundedReceiver, UnboundedSender};
use std::thread::{self, JoinHandle};

fn launch_sender_thread(tx: UnboundedSender<()>) -> JoinHandle<()> {
    thread::Builder::new()
        .name("sender thread".to_string())
        .spawn(move || loop {
            let _ = tx.unbounded_send(());
        })
        .unwrap()
}

fn launch_receiver_thread(rx: UnboundedReceiver<()>) -> JoinHandle<()> {
    thread::Builder::new()
        .name("receiver thread".to_string())
        .spawn(move || {
            let mut task = futures::executor::spawn(rx);
            match task.wait_stream() {
                Some(Ok(_)) => println!("thread2: received data"),
                Some(Err(e)) => println!("poll err {:?}", e),
                None => (),
            }
        })
        .unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let (sender, receiver) = futures::sync::mpsc::unbounded::<()>();
    let recv = launch_receiver_thread(receiver);
    let send = launch_sender_thread(sender);

    println!("Press Ctrl-C to abort");
    recv.join().unwrap();
    send.join().unwrap();
}
```

Notice, you can drive `tx` with task as well. It is just simpler to call `unbounded_send` here.

Comment: thanks! this actually was the key to fixing my problem:  `task.wait_stream()` , because I tested it without `join()` and it works too. thanks a lot